# OOP -- number of member variables and methods per class

Tags: java, oop

I've a class in Java which has 25 member variables but only two "useful" methods (excluding setters/getters). I feel as if there are 25 global variables being modified left, right and center, having no idea of what's going on. Is this normal ? Is there any "good practice" rule which says how many data members and methods can be reasonably encapsulated in a class ?

PS: I searched SO, but apparently this question hasn't been asked yet.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the other answers take a look at **TooManyFields** section of [pmd rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/java/codesize.html).

It is stated there that

> Classes that have too many fields can become unwieldy and could be
>   redesigned to have fewer fields, possibly through grouping related
>   fields in new objects. For example, a class with individual
>   city/state/zip fields could park them within a single Address field.

The other rules would also come in handy and you could use tools such as [pmd](http://pmd.sourceforge.net) and [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to get a better idea about how your code adheres to standards.

Comment: I ran PMD on my code and it indeed complains that my class has TooManyFields. Great link mate, thanks!

Comment: But let say I have 10 ImageButton in my app and I am using those buttons for different purpose. I have defined these 10 buttons as member variable. Is there any way to reduce this number of member variable in Android? IF you have any tip/suggestion for this than please kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How many? not that I know of.

But the rule I use is to keep variables in the smallest possible scope. If not all of the 25 members are representing the state of the object, not all of them need to be members.

Answer (score 1):

That certainly sounds wrong.

I would expect each class to have a [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and to delegate to and cooperate with other classes. If you have 25 members then it sounds like there's a lot going on. I would look to refactor this class:

1. identify what's going on (what operations/actions are being performed)
2. identify the groups of members involved in those tasks
3. extract these into objects performing that one role, and delegate to these objects where appropriate

It may be appropriate to do this within the class and thus render the refactoring as invisible to the client classes. However if you've got multiple setters/getters, I suspect that's unlikely.

However you perform the refactoring, make sure that area is covered by the appropriate set of unit tests.